# VS2010 x64 solution builds, but deploy project fails

Tags: visual-studio-2010, deployment, 64-bit

I have about 3 layers of Visual Studio solutions. Each one uses the compiled DLLs from the previous one to build a utility that is used within the website.

I have the task of converting everything to 64-bit. I have set every project to x64 processors within each project in all 3 solutions (apart from the .deploy project within the website; that only has the option of "Any CPU").

Every solution builds perfectly, no mention of processor mismatching.

However if I tick the build box next to the .deploy project it fails with a "**could not load file or assembly...an attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format**" error.

Am I right in thinking the problem lies with the deploy project rather than the code? Everything else builds, its just the deploy project that starts to moan. The fact that I can't select anything other than "Any CPU" is a little frustrating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The fact that I can't select anything other than "Any CPU" is a little frustrating.

It was probably meant to get you to do the Right Thing. You should select AnyCPU as the Platform target setting for the projects, not x64. AnyCPU says what it does, it will run as 64-bit code on a 64-bit operating system. And still work in 32-bit mode as well, such as used in Visual Studio which is a 32-bit process.  Do note that for managed projects, it is the Project + Properties, Build tab, Platform target setting that matters, not the name of the solution platform.  Set it to AnyCPU.  In VS2012 untick the "Prefer 32-bit" option.

Explicitly targeting x64 is only necessary for unmanaged code, such as generated by the C++ compiler.  It isn't clear from the question whether that applies.

Comment: Yep I think you're right. Setting everything to Any CPU did indeed seem to work and is a better solution.